# Why is PHP using a lot of memory to store a query result

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I use `Laravel 8` to perform a query on a `MySQL 8` table using the `query builder` directly to avoid `Eloquent` overhead but I'm getting a lot of memory consumption anyway.
To show you an example, I perform the following query to select exactly **300 000** elements.

My code looks like this:

```
$before = memory_get_usage();
$q_coords = DB::table('coords')->selectRaw('alt, lat, lng, id')
    ->where('active', 1)->take(300000)->get();

$after = memory_get_usage();
echo ($after - $before);
```

It displays **169760384** which means something like **169MB** if I'm not mistaking..
Looks like a lot to me because in my query I only asked for **2 float** and **2 bigInt**, which represents something like 4 x 8 bytes (**32 bytes**).
And.. 32 x 300 000 records ~= **9600000** (almost **10MB**).

How is that even possible that it uses so much memory? I am very surprised.

### EDIT

I also tried using `PDO` directly, same result.

```
$query = DB::connection()->getPdo()->query("select alt, lat, lng, id from coords WHERE active = 1 LIMIT 300000");
$q_coords = $query->fetchAll();
```

Comment: What is your question exactly ? cause 300 000 entries is not a normal behavior for any code. + in php each variable is contructed as a zend object + each result from Eloquent is converted to a PHP object...

Comment: @N69S I'm not using `Eloquent` to avoid the overhead due to `Models`, it's using `stdClass`. I get 300k entries to perform some calculation later, but here I'm just trying to understand why it does use that much memory for personal comprehension when I was expecting it to use less (because I know I can solve it using `chunks` or `cursors` anyway). It just seems a lot of stuff "around" to handle records of 32 bytes..

Comment: If you really need to access 300.000 records in a single query, so try using pdo directly and using `PDO::FETCH_NUM`.

Comment: How about `get()->toArray()`?

Comment: @Marc so this `->where('active', 1)->take(300000)->get()` is not eloquent ?

Comment: @N69S It could, but it's also part of the Query Builder which is my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP each variable is handled with a specific data structure to allow `dynamic typing`, `garbage collection` and more..
You can see here a (pretty old but still ok) article: [link](http://nikic.github.io/2011/12/12/How-big-are-PHP-arrays-really-Hint-BIG.html)

You can also see that arrays have a more specific processing, because it need a bucket, for example to store array keys which are considered as Strings.

All of that means there is (according to the article) approximately 144 bytes of data used to store an element of an array.
Well, while I can't explain EXACTLY your result, I can still tell you that in your case have something like this:

```
300 000 * 144 * 4 = 172 800 000
```

Which means **300000 rows** of **4 variables** with **144 bytes** by variable.

As you can see it's not that far away from what you got even if my maths are not taking into account the improvement done in PHP 7 and other factors...

Answer (score 2):

Because thet are represented as PHP objects in memory and not just as their raw data usage.
However there is a solution to limit the memory usage: [chunk](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#selects)

https://blackdeerdev.com/laravel-chunk-vs-cursor/

> Chunk: It will “paginate” your query, this way you use less memory.

Answer (score 1):

Since Laravel Query Builder uses `stdObj` to represent it results, you will have a lot of overhead:

Each object will store the value of the row itself, and the names of each column. So your 32 bytes turns into a lot of bytes.